# Требовать декорирование реализации абстрактного метода

Tags: python, ооп

Как сделать так, чтобы в классе реализующем `C`, требовалось продекорировать `method_one` и `method_two` переопределённым декоратором `decorator`? PyCharm молчит если убрать декоратор над реализованным методом.

```py
class C(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """"""

        return wrapper

    @decorator  # <-
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_one(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """"""

    @decorator  # <-
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_two(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """"""
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616269/20137863

Comment: Это что-то похожее на возможное решение, но я не уверен.